# How to use the awk to print the output

Tags: shell, shell-script, grep, awk

This command **nstats**  gives me output like below. How can I use awk or grep to give me the uptime with only days on it? I cannot use the  "" to get the output.

```
HOSTNAME  LOAD  MEMORY  SWAP  PROCS  TIME  UPTIME
Server    0.01     9%     3%    54  10:39  22 days 10:16:03
```

Answer (score 3):

With grep - `egrep -o "[0-9]+ days"`

```
(your nstats command) | sed -n '2p' | egrep -o "[0-9]+ days"
22 days
```

With awk - `awk '{print $14,$15}'`

```
(your nstats command) | sed -n '2p' | awk '{print $7,$8}'
22 days
```

With awk (just the days) - `awk '{print $14}'`

```
(your nstats command) | sed -n '2p' | awk '{print $7}'
22
```

Comment: The OP's nstats output was actually two lines of text, not one.

Comment: What do you mean two lines? I see just one line.

Comment: It's two lines in the markdown for the question (the actual text entered by the user), but it was being line-wrapped. The question has been edited to format the text correctly.

Comment: Yes, I see it now.. I edited my response accordingly.

Comment: That egrep answer is a nice one, here... I didn't know about `-o`; very useful!